# How can I quickly type a LaTeX accent in vim?

Tags: accents, vim

I want to write some text in Spanish in which accents are used frequently, such as *ó* for which I have to write `\'{o}`. I have seen that in [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) they have defined for example `` `a `` to convert into `\alpha` in math mode, but in normal mode I would like to convert it to for example *à*.

I also tried the command `:ab 'o \'{o}` but this only works with whole words, so not when it is part of a word. The same problem occurs when using snippets with [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips).

**How can I easily and quickly type an accented letter?**

Comment: for what its worth: you dont have to write the braces

Comment: You could just write ó  and tell latex which encoding you are using, such as `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` you do not have to use the ascii markup for accents unless you want to.

Comment: Ok thank you Bort and @David, that is even easier!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just write ó and tell latex which encoding you are using, such as

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

you do not have to use the ascii markup for accents unless you want to.

Comment: I knew you liked answering vim questions :)

Comment: You don't have to use accent commands, and you shouldn't if you want hyphenation, right? Or am I living in the 20th century?

Comment: @Gilles: I got a conference template with these accent commands, therefore I thought it would be necessary.

Comment: @Gilles even in the 20th century it made no difference to the typeset result whether you use `\'o` or `ó` (you do want to use T1 font encoding in either case to get hyphenation (`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`)

Comment: @agold if you have a keyboard like mine without the accented letters it's still easier to type `\'o` than remember what arcane combination of keystrokes produces ó

Comment: If you choose the right keyboard layout in the operating system it can make this easier. Linux and windows, I know, both have an US International layout where you would just type right-alt + o for that character.

Comment: @AndrewCashner exactly:-) altg+o makes ó on mine too, but what makes ò and either way it's easier to type `\'o` and `\\`o` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth you could achieve this with:

```
:imap 'o \'{o}
```