# Why can't I use accents in files included with \input?

Tags: input, accents

I am creating an article in which each section is a separate file, and I include them with `\input`. 
The following document compiles without error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
áéíóúñ
\end{document}
```

But, now I create a file `test2.tex` that contains the same line with accentuated letters:

```
áéíóúñ
```

And change the main document to input this file:

```
\begin{document}
áéíóúñ
\input{test2}
\end{document}
```

Now an error is given by latex:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.1 áéíó
            úñ
```

In worst case I could of course include all in one file, but I prefer to have them separated. **How can I separate the sections in files and still being able to use accents in those files?**

---

Note that in my previous question ([How can I quickly type a LaTeX accent in vim?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311772/how-can-i-quickly-type-a-latex-accent-in-vim)) they suggested to use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, however I found this not to work and now I use `\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}` as indicated in the congress' template.

Comment: you haven't really given enough clues but I would guess that your file is using a standard encoding such as UTF-8 not the legacy ansinew encoding which was never really a standard encoding anyway (it was an approximation based on the encoding capabilities of y&ytex of the non standard microsoft western European codepage)

Comment: You need that ***all*** files are `ansinew` encoded.

Comment: Ok, thanks! This is indeed the solution, I converted them to utf8 and changed the `\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}` to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is using a standard encoding such as UTF-8 not the legacy ansinew encoding which was never really a standard encoding anyway (it was an approximation based on the encoding capabilities of y&ytex of the non standard microsoft western European codepage).

Best solution would be to encode all files as UTF-8 and then use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

rather than `[ansinew]`

Comment: For additional infromation, refer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45448/how-can-i-tell-latex-that-an-input-file-is-in-a-different-encoding-from-inputen